# fuelphp No composer autoloader found

Tags: composer-php, fuelphp

I got error message when install fuelphp

```
No composer autoloader found. Please run composer to install the FuelPHP framework dependencies first!
```

Also i my composer is updated.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

I am using PHP7 with a Vagrant environment.

Any idea about this error ?

Comment: The composer autoloader is not where it is expected. What did you install? How? Add more information to allow anyone be able to reproduce that error, please.

Comment: sr, it my team fault. One of them removed fuel/core from composer.json

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find installation of fuelphp. Most common issue is that index.php("public" or "public_html" folder) does not have the fuelphp's app, core and packages path set properly.

change **DIR**.'../ to **DIR**.'/../../(goes back one folder level)

There should be three of them.